# How to oppose questions marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Since most people are lemmings, it often only takes 1 duplicate flag for a question to be closed as duplicate. (even if the so called duplicate does not even get close to answering the question).

What is the correct way to oppose such a flag?

Comment: I assume you are asking about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361003/how-to-not-print-a-trailing-newline-after-echo-something

Comment: In this particular case yes. But also more generic. I'm just wondering how the system is supposed to work by design when questions are wrongly flagged as duplicate.

Comment: As of now it doesn't contain a single close _vote_, only a flag.  Why panic?

Comment: The standard way would be to respond either with edits and/or comments to make it clear what the difference is.

Comment: @devnull There is no panic, only curiosity.

Comment: @gnat And that: is a perfect duplicate flag :) Nice find.

Comment: Which actually raises a different question: what if I agree if the duplicate is indeed correct. Is the best choice to delete this question? Or to leave it as a secondary way to actually find said duplicate ?

Comment: generally it is preferred to leave it there, as signpost for googlers to dupe-target, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: Will do then. And thank you :). Seems I can actually dupe-vote my own question, so did that.